# deploying 2 rails application on ec2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, github, amazon-ec2, push

i'm using Ubuntu 16.04 and installed docker on my machine and created 2 Hello World ruby on rails web application images.

The first one say **"Hello World"**, and the second say **"Howdy World"**. 
Ran both containers in parallel on my local machine, on different ports using the localhost.

Created a free AWS account, set up a VPC with a public subnet and spine up an EC2 instance with a public security group and created the relevant ssh credentials.

When I try to deploy the images to GitHub by pushing, the first one pushed fine, then second one however **doesn't seems to work** because I keep getting this

**error**
 `Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind it's remote counterpart. integrate the remote changes (git pull...) before pushing again`

after that I need to somehow run these 2 applications on the EC2 machine
(succeeded in connecting to the machine via Ubuntu terminal but got stuck since then)   so I could give it a public IP and with it's port, to and see them from any device that I connect.

Any help will be appreciated ?

Comment: As I understand, you want to run 2 applications in one VPS(ec2) ?

Comment: Unrelated, but neither you nor Amazon use "it's" correctly :p

Comment: yes, i want to run the 2 applications in one ec2, for example the first is 0.0.0.10\3000 (for hello world) and the second is 0.0.0.10\4000 (for howdy world)

Comment: @Liro, are yr apps dockerized already ? take a look this `https://rancher.com`. I could help you, but it just takes time to make it. Try to learn more about Rancher, you can run as many as images in one server.

Answer (score 0):

If the two applications are different repos on your local machine, you cannot push them to the same GitHub repository (hence the error about your branch being behind the remote because the histories are unrelated).

You should create a new GitHub repository and push to it instead.

Comment: i created two different repos on GitHub, but when i'm forcing it to be pushed, it's always to the first repository instead of the new one and i can't figure out why.

Answer (score 0):

You can resolve by two methods

Method 1 --> So, in that case, you need to push your content forcefully.
run below command

```
git push -f origin (branch name )
```

Method 2 --> first you need to update your local repo (it's in the case of using single repo for all files)

```
git pull
```

then push your content without using -f (forcefully)

```
git push origin (branch name)
```

Comment: i understood that from the first time i got the error, so i created another repository.
i tried to push the second container (even forced it) but still i'm getting this error.